# Moving a textview next to another textview off-screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout, textview, off-screen

I have a relative layout containing three textviews, each having a width of half-width of the screen. I want the user to be able to use a scroll gesture and move these textviews together, and if the textview located far left goes off-screen, it is moved to the far right next to the third textview. So I want to create a sort of a endless scroller-system.

However, using the code below results in gaps between the views when scrolling, and I think the gap widths are dependable on the scrolling speed.

Here is a link to a screenshot of the problem: http://postimg.org/image/bnl0dqsgd/

Currently I have implemented scrolling only for one direction.

**XML:**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:clipChildren="false"
    android:clipToPadding="false">

<com.app.healthview.BorderedTextView
    android:id="@+id/btvYear1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/YearColor1"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="2012" />

<com.app.healthview.BorderedTextView
    android:id="@+id/btvYear2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btvYear1"
    android:background="@color/YearColor2"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="2013" />

<com.app.healthview.BorderedTextView
    android:id="@+id/btvYear3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/YearColor1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/btvYear2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:text="2014" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Then I initialize the views in a function, which is called after setting the content view:

```
public void InitTimeView() {

    year_views = new BorderedTextView[3];
    year_views[0] = (BorderedTextView) findViewById(R.id.btvYear1);
    year_views[1] = (BorderedTextView) findViewById(R.id.btvYear2);
    year_views[2] = (BorderedTextView) findViewById(R.id.btvYear3);

    // Acquire display size
    display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int year_width = size.x / 2;

    year_views[0].setWidth(year_width);
    year_views[1].setWidth(year_width);
    year_views[2].setWidth(year_width);

    // This is done, because when scrolling, the third view which in the beginning is off-screen, could not be seen
    RelativeLayout relLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rel_layout);
    relLayout.getLayoutParams().width = year_width * 4;
    relLayout.invalidate();
}
```

**Then the onScroll-method:**

```
public boolean onScroll(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float distanceX, float distanceY) {
    // intCurrYearMember is public, it stores the view that is next to be moved
    // intRightYearMember; intCurrYearMember is located right to this view.
    switch(intCurrYearMember) {
    case 0:
        intRightYearMember = 2;
    case 1:
        intRightYearMember = 0;
    case 2:
        intRightYearMember = 1;
    }

    // Move the views
    for (TextView textview : year_views) {
        textview.setX(textview.getX() - (distanceX / 2));
    }

    // Check if the view most left is now too far on left, and move it if needed to far right
    if ((year_views[intCurrYearMember].getX() + year_views[intCurrYearMember].getWidth()) <= 0) {
        // Is the problem here perhaps?
        year_views[intCurrYearMember].setX(year_views[intRightYearMember].getRight());
        intPreviousMember = intCurrYearMember;
        if (intCurrYearMember < 2)
            intCurrYearMember++;
        else
            intCurrYearMember = 0;
    }

    return true;
}
```

As it shows in the code, my idea is to build a year scroller. If someone happends to have a better, more efficient idea for how to do it, I am happy to hear your advices!

So my question is: why are there gaps between the textviews?

Answer (score 0):

I would not suggest doing this at all. Utilizing Horizontal Swipes for these things is not a standard use of the platform and why waste your time developing this when there are already tested and pretty Android Components such as the [Pickers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html) that you can use easily.

A Horizontal Swiping gesture is normally saved for a Menu Drawer, View Pager, or other piece of functionality.

Comment: Thankyou for your reply! But if I am implementing this for a system, where those dates are x-values for a graph, which is drawn under the scroller? So the scroller can be thought as a horizontal axis for a line graph (which I haven't yet implemented). Then I would really need horizontal swipe.